# Old hard drive file permissions still there

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, permissions, file-permissions, ownership

I have a new hard drive, put Windows 7 on it and want to get all the files off of my old hard drive.  I put in my old hard drive as a slave drive.  I can see the files but when I try to move 'em, it tells me that I'm not the owner of the file.  I try to take ownership of the file and it doesn't work (it doesn't tell me that I can't take ownership of it, it goes through, just gives me the same error when I try and open the file again).  I've tried modding the permissions, no dice.

Anything else I can try?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keep a cd/usb drive with a copy of Ubuntu for tricky issues like this.
Boot from the cd/usb drive , browse to your drives and move around files .
When you are done simply remove the media and reboot your system.